# Is my woody old sage plant finished?

Tags: weed-control, herbs

I have an old woody sage plant (I *think* it's sage) in my herb garden. It's probably several years old and no longer looks in great shape. Also, I have allowed the grass and weeds to smother its base.

[image]

If I pruned it back and weeded it, would it come back good as new? Or is it best to start again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cut it back in stages, removing a third of the plant each year for three years. It takes time, but the results are normally satisfactory. Cut the old woody stems to 3 or 4 inches from the ground and cut out the dead stems each time you cut back. It would help the plant to keep other plants from growing around the base.

Comment: Agree. As scruffy as that sage looks, it's probably quite healthy!